# Detailed log dump of bluetooth activity?

Tags: catalina, bluetooth, airpods

I've looked everywhere on Google but could not find any info that could help me.

Running Catalina on Macbook 12" 2016.

Every now and then, the Bluetooth on my Macbook decides to die. I've tried restarting `bluetoothd` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Now, if I check ´launchctl´ I see this:

```
~ % launchctl list | grep -i bl                     
-   0   com.apple.bluetoothUIServer
```

Not sure if it's of any help.

When this happens, I almost always lose my AirPods; and when I try to re-pair them, the Bluetooth screen on the settings does recognise they're on the white LED pair mode, but when I see them on the list and hit "connect", nothing happens.

I know restarting my laptop will fix the issue, but is there a way to save my session without having to restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A detailed log dump of Bluetooth activity is not readily available in macOS. However, you may be able to gather some useful information by looking at the system logs. To do this, you can use the Console app on your Mac.

1. Open Console.app (you can find it in the Utilities folder within the Applications folder)
2. In the left column, select "Bluetooth"
3. Look for any error messages or logs related to Bluetooth activity.
4. If you're still unable to resolve the issue with your Bluetooth, you could try resetting the Bluetooth module on your MacBook. To do this, you can follow these steps:

   1. Open System Preferences → Bluetooth
   2. Turn off Bluetooth.
   3. Check **Show Bluetooth in menu bar** (if unchecked) to display Bluetooth icon in the Menu bar.
   4. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> keys and click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar.
   5. Click **Reset the Bluetooth module**.
   6. Note that resetting the Bluetooth module will disconnect any connected Bluetooth devices, so you may need to reconnect them after the reset is complete.

Comment: Thanks @Nimesh ! Interesting find about the Shift - Opt keys. Unfortunately this did not work. 
I did not find any "Bluetooth" option on the left Console.app column, but I did try to filter for "bluetooth" and will see if I get any iimportant info. I will mark it as solved because you did help me find what I needed!